# Task in later version of Scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm using Scalaz 7.6.12 and I cannot find the class `Task`. Has it been deprecated? I just started learning `Task` but I cannot find the class in my library.

Comment: There's no scalaz version 7.6.12. Perhaps you mean 7.2.16? It has `Task`. It is part of the [`scalaz-concurrent`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22scalaz-concurrent_2.12%22%20AND%20v%3A%227.2.16%22) package.

Comment: In the 2.11 I cannot find it.     compile group: 'org.scalaz', name: 'scalaz-core_2.11', version: '7.2.16'  Can you paste here the import that you use?. the typical scalaz.concurrent.Task does not work. Not even have the concurrent pàckage

Comment: You also need the artifact with `name: 'scalaz-concurrent_2.11'` in addition to `scalaz-core`.

Comment: Still dont get it working. which is the package you use in your import?, Also could you please paste here all dependencies that you have?. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check dependencies in your build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.2.16",
  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-concurrent" % "7.2.16"
)
```

If everything is in place, `Task` resides in `scalaz.concurrent` package as usual:

```
import scalaz.concurrent.Task
```